# Is it not possible for a function to return a constructor and create a new instance?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

I have the following JavaScript code, comprised of a function and two constructors:

```
function get_type(type){
    switch(type){
        default: case "a": return apple; break;
        case "b": return banana; break;
    }
}

function apple(color){
    this.color = color;
    this.age   = 0;
}

function banana(length,unit){
    this.length = length;
    this.unit   = unit||"cm";
    this.age    = 0;
}
```

When I try to create a variable `macintosh` with the value of `new get_type("a")("red")`, its value is `undefined`, even thought `get_type("a")` successfully returns the `apple` constructor.

Is there a problem with my code, or is it not possible to have function that returns a constructor?

## EDIT: Construction of variable `macintosh`.

```
var macintosh = new get_type("a")("red")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the specificity of the new operator. Your code basically behaves like this:

```
var macintosh = (new get_type("a"))("red")
```

Create an object of type `get_type` and then pass a parameter to it. What you want is this:

```
var macintosh = new (get_type("a"))("red")
```

First get the constructor, then use it.

Comment: Perfect! That makes sense. I'll accept when the time becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

You must issue a `new` in order to create a new instance.

```
function get_type(type){
switch(type){
    default: case "a": return new apple(); break;
    case "b": return new banana(); break;
 }
}
```

Comment: With `var macintosh = new get_type("a")("red");`, I get the error `TypeError: ({color:(void 0), age:0}) is not a function`

Comment: do what my answer suggests, your code is NOT returning an instance you are returning a ref to a function.